# Using urllib2 in Python

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to do the following via python:

From this website:
http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo

I would like to check the 4th checkbox and then click on Download image.

That is what I did:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
url = "http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo"
payload = {"chkArquivoDownload3_ativo":"1"}
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
request = urllib2.Request(url, data)

print request

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
contents = response.read()

print contents
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do we have any suggestions for what? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) is a great project, it lets you control a firefox browser with python. Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo')

browser.find_element_by_id('chkArquivoDownload3').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('imgSubmeter_ativo').click()

browser.quit()
```

would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers are a complex collection of components which interact together. 
Python does not have a web-browser built in (in particular a DOM or Javascript engine) and it is simply downloading a html file which would normally interact with said DOM and javascript in your browser.

The easiest method I foresee:

1. Pares the string using the python module BeautifulSoup.
2. Manually make the download request with the information you have parsed.
3. Save the downloaded image to file